# Add existing view to collectionview-cell

Tags: swift, view, uicollectionview

I'm currently working with a collectionview. 
So far, so good.
I've got 3 collectionview-cells. It can be scrolled horizontaly, and it works fine.

Now to my question. I would like to add, my already in XCode created UIViews, for each one of those collectionviewcells.
Now how can I achieve this the best way?

My UICollectionViewCell looks like following

```
import UIKit

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        //adding the already existing uiview
    }

}
```

How can I add uiviews to the cell, that I can horizontally scroll between those?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your custom `UIView` as the `UICollectionViewCell's` `subview` in `awakeFromNib`, i.e.

```
class CollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setupView()
    }

    func setupView()
    {
        self.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)) //your custom view
        customView.backgroundColor = .red
        self.addSubview(customView)
    }
}
```